# Elegantly adding data to a pandas.Panel within a running simulation

Tags: python, pandas, panel

## Disclaimer

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519643/plotting-the-same-column-from-various-dataframes-in-a-panel), where I had a `pandas.Panel` with several items consisting of `pandas.DataFrames`. I wanted to plot a certain column in my `DataFrame` (minor_axis in the `Panel`) from each item in only one command, avoiding a code cluster like

`plt.plot(x, DataFrame1[y1])
plt.plot(x, DataFrame2[y1])
...`
 
It was brought as an answer that I could switch my axes in the `Panel` so that instead of one item containing all the information of one dataset (of a simulation with a certain starting parameter), but rather just one information (e.g. yvalue `y1`) for all the different simulations an storing other parameters in other items (`DataFrames`).

---

## My basic simulation code

Even though my code is to simulate the behaviour of a pendulum I'll break it down to a general simulation code with returned values `y1-y3` instead of the real physical parameters. This simulation will be done for 2 different starting parameters `k`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Panel(major_axis=[], minor_axis=['x', 'sim1', 'sim2'])

# some kind of simulation resulting in 3 simulated values and with a
# starting parameter for different simulation "strengths"
# not sure whether to use a list or dict here
ks = {'sim1' = 0.5, 'sim2' = 1.0}
for k in ks:
    x, y1, y2, y3 = 0, 0, 0, 0
    while x<100:
        x += 1
        y1 += 1*ks[k]*x
        y2 += 2*ks[k]*x
        y3 += 3*ks[k]*x
        ...

# for example the y2 value for the different k values should be plottable like this 
data['y2'].plot()
```

---

## Question

My question now is how to elegantly (as few lines of code as possible) add/append each value for each simulation to `data`, considering there could be 5 or more simulations with 10 or more values for each simulation step?

E.g. in my problem [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519643/plotting-the-same-column-from-various-dataframes-in-a-panel) I'd create a new `DataFrame` and append it to my existing dataset for the given simulation - something like `data.append(pd.DataFrame([[x, y1, y2, y3]], columns=['x', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3']))`. But from there I couldn't plot properly with a single command but rather had to add a new graph for each simulation manually.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me understand how to build a `Panel` like this "on the run" - from my previous question I already know how to plot one :)

---

**UPDATE** I was asked for some example data, but since I want to consecutively add my simulated values into an Panel/item instead of generating a list first, I can only show how the data should look like in the end. In the beginning the Panel should look like this:

```
In [1]: print(data)
Out[1]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 0 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: y1 to y2
Major_axis axis: None
Minor_axis axis: x to sim2
```

In the following is shown how the simulations works and how for example the y1-item should look like in the end

```
In [2]: ks = {'sim1' : 0.5, 'sim2' : 1.0}
Out[2]: {'sim1': 0.5, 'sim2': 1.0}

In [3]:
for k in ks:
    x, y1, y2 = 0, 0, 0

    while x<3:
        x += 1
        y1 += 1*ks[k]*x
        y2 += 2*ks[k]*x
        # HERE is missing what I'm looking for
        # it should append e.g. the y1 value to data['y1'] for both k
Out[3]: ...

In [4]: print(data['y1'])
Out[4]:         
     x    sim1    sim2
0    1    0.5     1.0
1    2    1.5     3.0
2    3    3.0     6.0
```

I hope through this it's clearer now what I'm looking for - if not let me know

Answer (score 2):

I think the easies way to build a Pandas.Panel would be to build a dictionary of the following form:

```
d = {
    'items_axis_element0': DataFrame0,
    'items_axis_element1': DataFrame1,
    'items_axis_element2': DataFrame2,
    ...
}
```

now you can easily build up a Panel:

```
p = pd.Panel(d)
```

You may find some usefull examples in [Pandas Cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#panels)

---

**UPDATE:** here is slightly modified example from Pandas Cookbook:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2013',periods=100,freq='D')
data = np.random.randn(100, 4)
cols = ['A','B','C','D']
df1, df2, df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, rng, cols), pd.DataFrame(data, rng, cols), pd.DataFrame(data, rng, cols)

pf = pd.Panel({'df1':df1,'df2':df2})

In [21]: pf
Out[21]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 100 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: df1 to df2
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-04-10 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

now we can add `df3` as follows:

```
In [22]: pf.join(pd.Panel({'df3':df3}))
Out[22]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 100 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: df1 to df3
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-04-10 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

Comment: The problem is that the Cookbook always takes given sets of data and builds its `DataFrames` and `Panels` from the existing list or dictionary. Even adding to them is described, but again with complete sets of data - but I want to append to it step by step and I can't find an example for that in the Cookbook.

In pseudo-code I want to
`append a set of values of the simulation of a given parameter k to various DataFrames, each value in an extra item of the Panel`

Comment: @theGwiel, it's not quite clear - what are you going to add to the existing panel... Are you going to add a new DataFrame?

Comment: The workaround I came up with is defining the dictionary of DataFrames as you proposed (I don't find a option where I can insert a block of code like when I posted the question) and it looks like this:
`d = {'items0': pd.DataFrame(columns = ['x', 'y1_sim1', 'y1_sim2']),... }`

and adding to an item like this:  `d['items0'] = d['items0'].append(pd.DataFrame([[x, y1]], columns = ['x', 'y1_{}'.format(k)]), ignore_index = True)`

which uses the key of the `k`-parameter to append to the according column.

Comment: However, this method works but it wastes a lot of storage with NaN entrys (for each added simulation there are `n*(n-1)*(number of simulation steps)` NaN entries in each panel-item)

Comment: @theGwiel, it's difficult to understand what are you trying to achieve wihout clear and working sample and desired data sets

Comment: I initiate a panel with a known number of items (# of values returned by simulation), and a know number of columns (# of simulations I want to run). Now I want to generate e.g. a y1-value and append it to the first column of my y1-item in the panel, until the simulation is finished. Then I want to repeat that but append it to the second column. More clear? Sorry if I'm a little vague:/

Comment: @theGwiel, sorry, it's not clear to me until i see the __data__. Can you post a code that generates a simple Panel, then the data set (DataFrame?, etc.) that you want to append and desired data set?

Comment: I updated the post with a generated (empty) Panel and an example how a DataFrame (item) in the Panel should look like. I dont want to build a list of my `y1` values to append later on, but rather insert every value into the DataFrame as soon as it is simulated - or is this a totally wrong approach?